# Как выложить сайт на node js?

Tags: node.js, сервер, express, хостинг

Недавно "закончил" обучение node js + express js по курсу itProger(бесплатный). Теперь не могу выложить проект на хостинг или сервер. Ранее уже выкладывал свой сайт - чистый js+css+html, все получалось. Сейчас же написал простенький сайт + сервер(express js) и не понимаю где консоль, какие порты использовать и т.д. Желательно выложить все на какой нибудь бесплатный сервер-хостинг(ранее пользовался beget).
https://github.com/ilvemsh/project

Comment: На бесплатный с 99% вероятностью никак, покупайте нормальный vps и не мучайте себя

Comment: Сам не пробовал, но вроде на [AWS Cloud9](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/cloud9/pricing/) можно бесплатно, при соблюдении условий, о которых там почитаете. Однако, соглашусь с @andreymal, что свой VPS/VDS, при любом раскладе, будет лучшим вариантом.